# Toggling Animations when Using Animate.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm currently trying to have a panel I've made to animate in an out of the screen. i.e. when I  click on a button it animates onto the screen and when I click the same button again it animates off the screen. But What happens is the panel on page load is on the screen. When I click the button it animates fine off the screen and when I click on the button again it never animates back onto the screen. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... Here's my code:

```
 $(document).on('pageinit','#sellbookpage',
        function()
        {   
            flagclass = true;
            //button that gets clicked
            $('#SignUpLink').click(function() 
            {
                if(flagclass)
                {
                    $('#signinput').addClass("animated  fadeOutDownBig");
                    flagclass = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#signinput').addClass("animated  fadeOutUpBig");
                    flagclass = true;
                }

            }););
```

Basically the functionality I'm looking for is to have the panel animate in and out of the screen as I click on the button.

Comment: make a jsfiddle for this code and post the fiddle link .that helps to find the problem easily

Comment: First of all use the function animate to toggle fadeIn fadeOut [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/futkB/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sellbookpage').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var test = $('#signinput');
        if(test.hasClass('showed')) {
            test.removeClass('showed').fadeOut();
        }else{
            test.addClass('showed').fadeIn();
        }
    })
})
```

and add to input class showed if it's visible at the page load :)

http://jsfiddle.net/futkB/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem. I found this blog article that breaks it down, and how to solve it.

You use jQuery's one() function to detect the end of the css3 animation. Then you will remove any animated.css classes like animate etc...

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end

So your code would look like this

```
$('#signinput').addClass("animated  fadeOutDownBig")
    .one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',   
        function(e) {
            $(this).removeClass('animated fadeOutDownBig');
        }
    );
```